# Cat a file with grep, showing current "cat" line

Tags: awk, files, grep, cat

I search through a HUGE file with `cat` and `grep`. I need to know on which line is `cat` all the time.

If i want to search `ball`:

```
cat file.txt | grep ball
```

FILE:

```
football
tennis
hockey
basketball
...
```

WHAT I NEED:

```
1. row - football [1/1000]
2. row - [2/1000]
2. row - [3/1000]
3. row - basketball [4/1000]
```

Comment: Would getting the line number (and not the total lines in the file) in front of each line be enough for you?

Comment: Of course it would be enough. Total lines i do with "wc -l file"

Comment: `awk '/ball/{print $0 " ["NR"]" }' file.txt`

Comment: This is not exactly what i want. I want to see all the time the number of line where awk or cat is. Like printing percentage example: print("{}% Complete".format(percent), end="\r"). That current line of awk or cat will be printed on same line, updating every "tick".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete **`awk`** + **`wc`** approach:

Sample `file.txt`:

```
football
tennis
hockey
basketball
boxing
```

---

```
awk -v t=$(wc -l file.txt | cut -d' ' -f1) '{ printf "%s[%d/%d]\n",(/ball/? $0" ":""),NR,t }' file.txt
```

The output:

```
football [1/4]
[2/4]
[3/4]
basketball [4/4]
[5/5]
```

Comment: What i didn't mention is if isn't found anything on line, the line numbers will be printed on same line, so it will not be so messy in the output.

Comment: @PavelMeduna, then update your **WHAT I NEED** section with actual expected result

Comment: I made it. Little edit of your command. `awk -v t=$(wc -l file.txt | cut -d' ' -f1) '{ printf "%s[%d/%d]\r", (/admin/? $0"\n":""), NR, t }' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Doing `grep -n ball file.txt` will output

```
1:football
4:basketball
```